# Recommended Docker base image

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I have noticed recently many people from Alpine back to Ubuntu and Debian after few years of hype around Alpine. Ubuntu appears to have better official support (e.g. [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images), [Java](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk)). I understand the issues with Alpine, such as performance and compatibility problems related to musl.

I would like to know what is the recommended base image nowadays. Particularly I am interested in the reasons for choosing Debian over Ubuntu, or vice versa. Both have minimal images (bionic and buster-slim both around 25MB compressed), so size should be irrelevant. Are there some differences regarding security that one should be aware of?

So, what would be recommended general purpose base image? By general purpose, I mean an image suitable for most use cases and containing the basic unix tools. Consequently, building image from scratch is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, A vs B questions are not accepted here. You can fix your question easily, by just listing your requirements. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul changed the question a bit. I want to know what is the generally recommended base image and why, i.e. what kind of requirements have led to choosing the particular image. I assume this is the place for such questions?

Comment: Thanks for editing! Still, the concept of this site is that you must come with solid requirements, so the "and why? part is off-topic. Please read https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/is-tool-x-versus-tool-y-an-on-topic-question and try to think about what you really want from your Docker image, and express it as objective requirements. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul As I said, I want to know what is *generally* recommended base image, i.e. an image suitable to most situation regardless of requirements. I guess it is impossible to edit the question in such a way to satisfy the strict guidelines?

Comment: Yes, if you want to keep your question general (for instance if you have no strict requirements yet), then a forum such as Reddit or Quora is more appropriate. Thanks for your understanding!